# Why are my resistance spot welds not holding?

Tags: welding

My core support frame got hit & broke many of top factory spot welds. I have Chicago Electric spot welder but my welds are not holding. Rather then mess up the car further I'm now doing test welds with similar size sheet metal.
I test these scrap metals by dropping them, which they pass. I test car frame by shaking it which passes sometimes. Then I test them by inserting screw driver & twisting which they fail unless there is holds on both sides of the weld.

This picture is the first welds I tried which worked great, but I think its because of the holds on either side of the metal. The metals
[image]

This picture, only the bottom right weld held, but its also a thin strip of metal.
[image]

I also clean the metal with air powered hard sponge like thing which was recommended for stripping paint but not damaging the sheet metal. The scraps & the frame are about 1/16 of an inch thickness & the welder is go for 3/16 of an inch.

Comment: What material is that in the photos?  It looks like stainless steel.

Comment: I'm not sure in came out of a old CD drive & cable box. Does it make a difference?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't get good welds in stainless steel using an standard spot welder.  You might try your test welds using some steel.